# Adaptive Server Enterprise on Docker container

Tags: docker, pyodbc, sap-ase, unixodbc

I managed to install FreeTDS driver in a `python:3.7-alpine` container, now I want to add Adaptive Server Enterprise driver. I need it because I need to run queries on a Sybase db in order to populate the PostgreSQL db on my Django app.

Anyone knows how to do this Dockerfile image?

My Dockerfile now is:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER HJ23

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client

RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev freetds-dev postgresql-dev

RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver\n\
Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
Setup = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/odbc/libtdsS.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app/ /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

If I run `pyodbc.drivers()` I get `['FreeTDS']`, it will be nice to get `['FreeTDS', 'Adaptive Server Enterprise']`

Comment: Hey! I am working on a similar problem. Did you figure out how to do this? Thanks in advance!